# Slow Read Speeds on External Hard Disk

Tags: openwrt

I have a strange issue on my OpenWrt 18.06.4, where I have connected an external hard disk via USB. I have good write speeds via samba and rsync (4MB/s or 32Mb/s), whereas I only get around 300KB/s or 2.34Mb/s read speeds using samba and rsync. I have done HDD read and write speeds using dd and I get around 6MB/s read speed and over 4MB/s write speed. Please help.

Comment: Wouldn't call that a very good read speed, I'd expect ~15-20 MB/s over USB 2.0 depending on how powerful the device is. What CPU load do you see while doing a transfer (both 'dd' and 'rsync')?

Comment: My read speed is lower than write speeds. I only get 300KB/s read speeds. CPU load is nominal (around 40-70%) on dd, rsync and samba.